# ServiceNow email notification with embeded survey

Tags: dom, survey, servicenow, jelly

I have seen other developers create an email notification and embed the first question of the survey. https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=32f20ba1dbd8dbc01dcaf3231f961948

In my case, I am sending 5 Smiley faces from very Dissatisfied(1) to Very Satisfied(5). Each smiley face has a rating/score when the client clicks on it. when it is clicked, I want the survey rating to be populated to the corresponding rating  on the survey form and then allow the user to complete the remaining questions.
I have the notification working and each smiley has the url link to the survey with appropriate grade parameter.
I have no experience with gelly or DOM. 
Can anyone share appropriate code that I can use to accomplish this?  Or lead me in the right direction?
It is greatly appreciated.
[Notification Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGdcn.jpg)

Comment: It's jelly, not gelly

Comment: My mistake, meant jelly.

Comment: I didnt realize I could edit the tags.  Edited it to be right tag.

Answer (score 1):

So this sounds a lot like this [ask](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=37113a00dbc39704d58ea345ca9619e8).  I answered it and posted about it on my [blog here](https://blog.jacebenson.com/email-links-that-do-things).

Pretty much you would need to make the links dynamically in the email with url parameters, and handle redirection if any or the message;  This could work if you links were in the following format;

https://instance.service-now.com/custom_survey_response.do?response=1&incident=INC12345

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
  <g2:evaluate var="jvar_unwrapped_url" jelly="true">
    var currentUser = gs.getUserID();
    var incidentFromURL = RP.getParameterValue('incident');
    var responseFromURL = RP.getParameterValue('response');
    var link = '';
    var incident = new GlideRecord('incident');
    if(incident.get('number', incidentFromURL)) { //found incident
      // query survey tables, and do an insert on appropriate tables
      // currentUser is string of user sys_id,
      // incident is gliderecord of incident
      // responseFromURL is the numeric value set by the url param in your notification
    }
  </g2:evaluate>
  ${gs.getMessage("Thanks for your response")}
</j:jelly>
```